# Mysql query to compare records in different columns and find the biggest number

Tags: mysql

Hi i would like to get a right query for the following scenario:

```
user_id  english   physics    geography   chemistry

  1        75        60          85          79
```

I would like to have a mysql query that will compare the results and return the subject name/column he has got the **highest number.**

So here we see user one got highest in geography. I want to get this column name(geography) with mysql query.

This is the fiddle link: [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa59/1)

Comment: What is your table structure? If I got your goal right you post expected result

Comment: Hi @Alex. This is the table structure:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa59/1

Comment: @Strawberry what's that?

Comment: It's the single most fundamental concept pertaining to RDBMSs, such as MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the value using the MySQL functions [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) and [`ELT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt):

```
SELECT user_id,
    GREATEST(english, physics, geography, chemistry) AS points,
    ELT(
      FIELD(
        GREATEST(english, physics, geography, chemistry),
        english, physics, geography, chemistry
      ),
      'english', 'physics', 'geography', 'chemistry'
    ) AS class
FROM results;
```

#### How it works

```
GREATEST(english, physics, geography, chemistry)
```

gets the greatest value from the indicated columns. It returns `85`.

```
FIELD(
  GREATEST(english, physics, geography, chemistry),
  english, physics, geography, chemistry
)
```

compares the values returned by `GREATEAST()` (`85`) with the values passed as the next arguments to `FIELD()` and returns the position of the first value that is equal with the value returned by `GREATEST()`. It returns `3`.

```
ELT(
  FIELD(
    GREATEST(english, physics, geography, chemistry),
    english, physics, geography, chemistry
  ),
  'english', 'physics', 'geography', 'chemistry'
) AS class
```

`ELT()` uses the index returned by `FIELD()` (`3`) to select the value at that index from the list of its next arguments. It returns `geography`.

#### Remarks

While this query delivers the expected result, you can simply `SELECT *` and find the greatest value and the column it contains in the client code (assuming you are not writing a MySQL stored procedure).

Depending on the structure and needs of your application, also consider having a table that contains `user_id`, `class_id` and `points`; it stores several rows for each user, each row containing the number of points the user got on a single class.

Comment: such a nice and detailed answer. Let me check for a while and come back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f369/1

```
SELECT *,
  @m:=GREATEST(`english`, `physics`, `geography`, `chemistry`),
  IF(@m=`english`,'english',
     IF(@m=`physics`,'physics',
        IF(@m=`geography`,'geography',
           'chemistry'
        )
     )
  )
FROM results;
```